# angular 6 set validator required based on parent formValues

Tags: angular, validation, conditional-statements

I have a nested formGroup and would like set a validator (Required) based on a parent value.

```
this.userForm = fb.group({
  audio: [''],
  audioSet: fb.group({
    producer: [0, this.userForm.get('audio').value ? Validators.required : '']
  }),
})
```

But `this.userForm.get('audio').value` throw undefined a this time (normal).

```
DetailsComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
at new DetailsComponent (details.component.ts:24)
at createClass (core.js:9303)
at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:9186)
at createViewNodes (core.js:10406)
at createRootView (core.js:10320)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11351)
at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:10838)
at ComponentFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:8666)
at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:3315)
at ViewContainerRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (core.js:8776)
```

So i set the validator on valueChange:

```
    this.userForm.controls['audio'].valueChanges.subscribe(result => {
  const ctrl = this.userForm.get(['audioSet', 'producer']);
  if (result) {
    ctrl.setValidators(Validators.required);
    ctrl.updateValueAndValidity();
  } else {
    ctrl.setValidators(null);
    ctrl.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
});
```

I have plenty of values in my nested formGroup,
Is it a better or new way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

> You should call the `get`as `Function` but you are treating `get` it as an `Array`

Change it

```
this.userForm.get['audio'].value
```

to

```
this.userForm.get('audio').value
```

Comment: I got this error in formBuilder: RROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: It means formBuilder is not Injected in `constructor`. Print the log in constructor and check if is initialized or it is `undefined.`

Comment: the fb is initialized: constructor(fb: FormBuilder) and i use it in constructor

Comment: I tried olso set it in private, and updated my question. thanks